# How to do arithemetic operations in mysql stored procedures?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to do some arithmetic operations in MySQL stored procedures.

```
declare socSecAmt as double;
SET status_flag=0;
SET socSecAmt = (socSec/100)*fixedsal;
```

But the above fails. `socSec` and `fixedsal` as variables which gets the value from the statement which calls the stored procedure.

Full SP code.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `pro_empsalaryinfo_dao` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `pro_empsalaryinfo_dao`(

IN salid        varchar(15),
IN empcode      varchar(12),
IN empname      varchar(75),
IN empgender    varchar(8),
IN empage       varchar(5),
IN salarytype   varchar(10),
IN saldate      date,
IN salmonth     varchar(5),
IN salyear      varchar(4),
IN paidamt      double(10,2),
IN paiddetails  text,
IN advancepaid  double(10,2),
IN balamt       double(10,2),
IN fixedsal     double(10,2),
IN socSec       double(5, 1),
IN functionality  varchar(10),
OUT status_flag    INT
)
BEGIN
declare socSecAmt as double;

SET status_flag=0;
SET socSecAmt = (socSec/100)*fixedsal;



IF(functionality='save') THEN

insert into emp_salary_info (sal_id,emp_code,emp_name,gender,age,salary_type,sal_date,paid_amt,paid_details,
sal_month,sal_year,advance_paid,bal_amt,fixed_sal,soc_sec,soc_sec_amt)values
(salid,empcode,empname,empgender,empage,salarytype,saldate,paidamt,paiddetails,
salmonth,salyear,advancepaid,balamt,fixedsal,socSec,socSecAmt);

SET status_flag=1;

elseif(functionality='update') then

UPDATE emp_salary_info set sal_id=salid, emp_code=empcode, emp_name=empname, gender=empgender, age=empage, salary_type=salarytype, sal_date=saldate, paid_amt=paidamt, paid_details=paiddetails, 
sal_month=salmonth, sal_year=salyear, advance_paid=advancepaid, bal_amt=balamt, fixed_sal=fixedsal,soc_sec = socSec,soc_sec_amt=socSecAmt, esal_flag_id=0 where sal_id = salid and esal_flag_id='0';

SET status_flag=2;

else
SET status_flag=0;

end if;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Error message displayed after running the above code is,

```
Script line: 4  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as double;

SET status_flag=0;
SET socSecAmt = (socSec/100)*fixedsal;

SET ' at line 22
```

Comment: What error are you facing?

Comment: srry for the confusion, `@` is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the wrong variable.  `socSecAmt` and `@socSecAmt` are different things.

Perhaps you want:

```
declare @socSecAmt as double;
SET status_flag=0;
SET @socSecAmt = (socSec/100)*fixedsal;
```

Comment: What's the diff between with using `@` and without using `@` before variable names?

Comment: then how my insert query will look like? `insert tab .. values(@socSecAmt)?` ie, did I have to include `@` also in the query?

Comment: sorry, `@` before the var name is a typo.

Comment: I would like to hear from you. Did you want me to show the full SP code?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it by declaring the variable `socSecAmt` as `Decimal`,

```
DECLARE socSecAmt DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT 0;

SET status_flag=0;
SET socSecAmt = (socSec/100)*fixedsal;
```

Comment: I think the problem was the `as` and not the type.